# How to use Sencha CMD with Cordova to generate WP8 and Android app

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha Touch 2.3.1 with Sencha CMD 4.0.2.67 in conjunction with Cordova 3.4.

The purpose of my doing is to know how to use Sencha tools to create the mobile app and then using Sencha CMD + Cordova to build and run on Android and Windows Phone 8 platforms.(I have set up both environment on my PC and managed to build and run my mobile app just with Cordova for Android and WP8).

Now, I followed the tutorial on Sencha about creating the 1st app(http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/first_app), encountered many odd crashes but fortunately, I somehow fixed all of them(I'm surprised by myself). The learning procedure is very exciting for me so far and I found that Sencha CMD and even starts WP and Android emulators!

Now the problem is, when I execute the command `sencha app build -run native`, both platforms have my app generated and run, but the panels I created under Sencha, do not show up. What I get is the launching screen with 4 flashing dots.

It supposes to show a UI which has 3 tabPanels.

Here is my app.js:

```
launch: function () {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: "bottom",

            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    cls: 'home',

                    html: [
                         '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
                        "to use tabs, lists, and forms to create a simple app.</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch</h2>'
                    ].join("")

                },
                { // the 2nd item}, {// the 3rd one}
```

And here is what the Sencha generated under MyApp/cordova/platforms/wp8 in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MySenCha</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /**
         * Example of an initial loading indicator.
         * It is recommended to keep this as minimal as possible to provide instant feedback
         * while other resources are still being loaded for the first time
         */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #1985D0;
        }

        #appLoadingIndicator {
            position: absolute;
         
              // many lines of generated css
            }
        }
    </style>
    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Command to build your application -->
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(e){var c=e.document.head||e.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],b=e.Ext;if(typeof b=="undefined"){e.Ext=b={}}function d(f){document.write(f)}function a(f,g){var h=document.createElement("meta");h.setAttribute("name",f);h.setAttribute("content",g);c.appendChild(h)}b.blink=function(q){var k=q.js||[],o=q.css||[],m,n,p,h,l,g;if(navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)){var j=document.createElement("style");j.appendChild(document.createTextNode("@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {@-ms-viewport {width: 320px !important;}}@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {@-ms-viewport {width: 560px !important;}}"));document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(j)}a("viewport","width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no");a("apple-mobile-web-app-capable","yes");a("apple-touch-fullscreen","yes");b.microloaded=true;var f=window.Ext.filterPlatform=function(u){var D=false,s=navigator.userAgent,w,A;u=[].concat(u);function z(E){var i=/Mobile(\/|\s)/.test(E);return/(iPhone|iPod)/.test(E)||(!/(Silk)/.test(E)&&(/(Android)/.test(E)&&(/(Android 2)/.test(E)||i)))||(/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(E)&&i)||/(Windows Phone)/.test(E)}function y(i){return !z(i)&&(/iPad/.test(i)||/Android|Silk/.test(i)||/(RIM Tablet OS)/.test(i)||(/MSIE 10/.test(i)&&/; Touch/.test(i)))}var r=window.location.search.substr(1),t=r.split("&"),v={},B,x;for(x=0;x<t.length;x++){var C=t[x].split("=");v[C[0]]=C[1]}B=v.platform;if(B){return u.indexOf(B)!=-1}for(w=0,A=u.length;w<A;w++){switch(u[w]){case"phone":D=z(s);break;case"tablet":D=y(s);break;case"desktop":D=!z(s)&&!y(s);break;case"ios":D=/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/.test(s);break;case"android":D=/(Android|Silk)/.test(s);break;case"blackberry":D=/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(s);break;case"safari":D=/Safari/.test(s)&&!(/(BlackBerry|BB)/.test(s));break;case"chrome":D=/Chrome/.test(s);break;case"ie10":D=/MSIE 10/.test(s);break;case"windows":D=/MSIE 10/.test(s)||/Trident/.test(s);break;case"tizen":D=/Tizen/.test(s);break;case"firefox":D=/Firefox/.test(s)}if(D){return true}}return false};for(m=0,n=o.length;m<n;m++){p=o[m];if(typeof p!="string"){h=p.platform;g=p.exclude;l=p.theme;p=p.path}if(h){if(!f(h)||f(g)){continue}if(!b.theme){b.theme={}}if(!b.theme.name){b.theme.name=l||"Default"}}d('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+p+'">')}for(m=0,n=k.length;m<n;m++){p=k[m];if(typeof p!="string"){h=p.platform;g=p.exclude;p=p.path}if(h){if(!f(h)||f(g)){continue}}d('<script src="'+p+'"><\/script>')}}})(this);Ext.blink({id:"19f378b6-7681-4874-9579-87ab900c2cde",js:[{path:"cordova.js",remote:true},{path:"app.js",update:"delta"}],css:[{path:"resources/css/app.css",update:"delta"}]});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="appLoadingIndicator">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see here "Ext.Blink(id......., .... ,...., js:[xxxx,'app.js'])".

So here is the app.js under wp8/www folder

```
(function(){var global=this,...many code more than 570000 letters, so I have to cut the m down..................if(window.scrollY!==0){window.scrollTo(0,0)}}})}}});Ext.define("Ext.viewport.WindowsPhone",{requires:[],alternateClassName:"Ext.viewport.WP",extend:Ext.viewport.Default,config:{translatable:{translationMethod:"csstransform"}},initialize:function(){var a=function(d){var c=d.srcElement.nodeName.toUpperCase(),b=["INPUT","TEXTAREA"];if(b.indexOf(c)==-1){return false}};document.body.addEventListener("onselectstart",a);this.callParent(arguments)},supportsOrientation:function(){return false},onResize:function(){this.waitUntil(function(){var c=this.windowWidth,f=this.windowHeight,e=this.getWindowWidth(),a=this.getWindowHeight(),d=this.getOrientation(),b=this.determineOrientation();return((c!==e&&f!==a)&&d!==b)},function(){var b=this.getOrientation(),a=this.determineOrientation();this.fireOrientationChangeEvent(a,b)},Ext.emptyFn,250)}});Ext.define("Ext.viewport.Viewport",{constructor:function(b){var c=Ext.os.name,d,a;switch(c){case"Android":d=(Ext.browser.name=="ChromeMobile")?"Default":"Android";break;case"iOS":d="Ios";break;case"Windows":d=(Ext.browser.name=="IE")?"WindowsPhone":"Default";break;case"WindowsPhone":d="WindowsPhone";break;default:d="Default";break}a=Ext.create("Ext.viewport."+d,b);return a}});Ext.define("MySenCha.view.Main",{extend:Ext.tab.Panel,xtype:"main",config:{tabBarPosition:"bottom",items:[{title:"My Home",iconCls:"home",styleHtmlContent:true,scrollable:true,items:{docked:"top",xtype:"titlebar",title:"Welcome to Sencha Touch 2"},html:["You've just generated a new Sencha Touch 2 project. What you're looking at right now is the ","contents of <a target='_blank' href=\"app/view/Main.js\">app/view/Main.js</a> - edit that file ","and refresh to change what's rendered here."].join("")},{title:"Get Started",iconCls:"action",items:[{docked:"top",xtype:"titlebar",title:"Getting Started"},{xtype:"video",url:"http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c",posterUrl:"http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg"}]}]}});Ext.application({name:"MySenCha",views:["Main"],icon:{"57":"resources/icons/Icon.png","72":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png","114":"resources/icons/Icon@2x.png","144":"resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png"},isIconPrecomposed:true,startupImage:{"320x460":"resources/startup/320x460.jpg","640x920":"resources/startup/640x920.png","768x1004":"resources/startup/768x1004.png","748x1024":"resources/startup/748x1024.png","1536x2008":"resources/startup/1536x2008.png","1496x2048":"resources/startup/1496x2048.png"},launch:function(){Ext.fly("appLoadingIndicator").destroy();Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel",{fullscreen:true,tabBarPosition:"bottom",items:[{title:"Home",iconCls:"home",cls:"home",html:['<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',"<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>","<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ","to use tabs, lists, and forms to create a simple app.</p>","<h2>Sencha Touch</h2>"].join("")},{xtype:"nestedlist",title:"Blog",iconCls:"star",displayField:"title",store:{type:"tree",fields:["title","link","author","contentSnippet","content",{name:"leaf",defaultValue:true}],root:{leaf:false},proxy:{type:"jsonp",url:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog",reader:{type:"json",rootProperty:"responseData.feed.entries"}}},detailCard:{xtype:"panel",scrollable:true,styleHtmlContent:true},listeners:{itemtap:function(e,d,a,c,b){this.getDetailCard().setHtml(b.get("content"))}}},{title:"Contact",iconCls:"user",xtype:"formpanel",url:"contact.php",layout:"vbox",items:[{xtype:"fieldset",title:"Contact Us",instructions:"(email address is optional)",height:285,items:[{xtype:"textfield",label:"Name"},{xtype:"emailfield",label:"Email"},{xtype:"textareafield",label:"Message"}]},{xtype:"button",text:"Send",ui:"confirm",handler:function(){this.up("formpanel").submit()}}]}]})},onUpdated:function(){Ext.Msg.confirm("Application Update","This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",function(a){if(a==="yes"){window.location.reload()}})}});
```

I finally found where my code, as you might see that my code has been included in the app.js under wp8/www folder.

But when I tried to run from the index.html or deploy the app onto my device, I only got Cordova splash screen and a blue screen, no my tab panels at all.

I also checked the log generated during building and running my app and found that when running WP8 app, it said:

> [TypeError: undefined is not a function]

Then I when to the generated index.html and did find many of them.

Incidentally, I ran my app on 3 browsers: IE10, Chrome (latest), Firefox (just downloaded). Only Firefox can run the Sencha Touch app successfully. The rest of others just can show the blue screen in the demo without characters and pic, no tab panels docked at the bottom either.

I feel like I am very close to the final success of my learning.

### Update 1

File : MySenCha/app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MySenCha',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],

    views: [
        'Main'
    ],

    icon: {
        '57': 'resources/icons/Icon.png',
        '72': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad.png',
        '114': 'resources/icons/Icon@2x.png',
        '144': 'resources/icons/Icon~ipad@2x.png'
    },

    isIconPrecomposed: true,

    startupImage: {
        '320x460': 'resources/startup/320x460.jpg',
        '640x920': 'resources/startup/640x920.png',
        '768x1004': 'resources/startup/768x1004.png',
        '748x1024': 'resources/startup/748x1024.png',
        '1536x2008': 'resources/startup/1536x2008.png',
        '1496x2048': 'resources/startup/1496x2048.png'
    },

    launch: function () {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: "bottom",

            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    cls: 'home',

                    html: [
                         '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>You're creating the Getting Started app. This demonstrates how ",
                        "to use tabs, lists, and forms to create a simple app.</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch</h2>'
                    ].join("")

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'nestedlist',
                    title: 'Blog',
                    iconCls: 'star',
                    displayField: 'title',
                    store: {
                        type: 'tree',
                        fields: [
                            'title', 'link', 'author', 'contentSnippet', 'content', { name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true }
                        ],

                        root: { leaf: false },

                        proxy: {
                            type: 'jsonp',
                            url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    detailCard: {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        scrollable: true,
                        styleHtmlContent: true
                    },

                    listeners: {
                        itemtap: function (nestedList, list, inde, element, post) {
                            this.getDetailCard().setHtml(post.get('content'));
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Contact',
                    iconCls: 'user',
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    url: 'contact.php',
                    layout: 'vbox',

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'fieldset',
                            title: 'Contact Us',
                            instructions: '(email address is optional)',
                            height: 285,
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    label: 'Name'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                                    label: 'Email'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                                    label: 'Message'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: "button",
                            text: 'Send',
                            ui: 'confirm',
                            handler: function () {
                                this.up('formpanel').submit();
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        });

        //// Initialize the main view
        //Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MySenCha.view.Main'));
    },

    onUpdated: function () {
        Ext.Msg.confirm(
            "Application Update",
            "This application has just successfully been updated to the latest version. Reload now?",
            function (buttonId) {
                if (buttonId === 'yes') {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

File : app.json

```
{
    /**
     * The application's namespace, used by Sencha Command to generate classes
     */
    "name": "MySenCha",

    /**
     * The file path to this application's front HTML document, relative to this app.json file
     */
    "indexHtmlPath": "index.html",

    /**
     * The absolute URL to this application in development environment, i.e: the URL to run this application
     * on your web browser during development, e.g: "http://localhost/myapp/index.html".
     *
     * This value is needed when build to resolve your application's dependencies if it requires server-side resources
     * that are not accessible via file system protocol.
     */
    "url": "http://localhost:1841/index.html",

    /**
     * List of all JavaScript assets in the right execution order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/script.js" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true              // (Optional)
     *                                      // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                      // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"           // (Optional)
     *                                      //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                      //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed.
     *                                      //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                      //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *          "x-bootstrap": true         // (Optional)
     *                                      // Indicates a development mode only dependency.  
     *                                      // These files will not be copied into the build directory or referenced
     *                                      // in the generate app.json manifest for the micro loader.
     *
     *      }
     */
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "cordova.js",
            "remote": true
        },
        {
            "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
            "x-bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "bootstrap.js",
            "x-bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.js",
            "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
     * Each item is an object with the following format:
     *      {
     *          "path": "path/to/item.css" // Path to file, if local file it must be relative to this app.json file
     *          "remote": true             // (Optional)
     *                                     // - Defaults to undefined (falsey) to signal a local file which will be copied
     *                                     // - Specify true if this file is a remote file which will not to be copied
     *          "update": "delta"          // (Optional)
     *                                     //  - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
     *                                     //    cached inside localStorage until this value is changed to either one below
     *                                     //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
     *                                     //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
     *
     *      }
     */
    "css": [
        {
            "path": "resources/css/app.css",
            "update": "delta"
        }
    ],

    /**
     * Used to automatically generate cache.manifest (HTML 5 application cache manifest) file when you build
     */
    "appCache": {
        /**
         * List of items in the CACHE MANIFEST section
         */
        "cache": [
            "index.html"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the NETWORK section
         */
        "network": [
            "*"
        ],
        /**
         * List of items in the FALLBACK section
         */
        "fallback": []
    },

    /**
     * Extra resources to be copied along when build
     */
    "resources": [
        "config.xml",
        "resources/images",
        "resources/icons",
        "resources/startup"
    ],

    /**
     * File / directory name matchers to ignore when copying to the builds, must be valid regular expressions
     */
    "ignore": [
        "\.svn$"
    ],

    /**
     * Directory path to store all previous production builds. Note that the content generated inside this directory
     * must be kept intact for proper generation of deltas between updates
     */
    "archivePath": "archive",

    /**
     * List of package names to require for the cmd build process
     */
    "requires": [
    ],

    /**
     * Uniquely generated id for this application, used as prefix for localStorage keys.
     * Normally you should never change this value.
     */
    "id": "19f378b6-7681-4874-9579-87ab900c2cde"
}
```

### Update 2

Here is the log for running: cordova run --device.

```
    F:\Workplace\TestSenchaApp\cordova>cordova run --device
Preparing wp8 project
[TypeError: undefined is not a function]
Running command: cmd args=["/c","F:\\Workplace\\TestSenchaApp\\cordova\\platforms\\wp8\\cordova\\run","--device"]
WARNING: [ --debug | --release | --nobuild ] not specified, defaulting to --debug.

Cleaning cordova project...
Building Cordova-WP8 Project:
        Configuration : Debug
        Directory : F:\Workplace\TestSenchaApp\cordova\platforms\wp8
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  TestSenchaApp -> F:\Workplace\TestSenchaApp\cordova\platforms\wp8\Bin\Debug\com.test.myApp.dll
  Begin application manifest generation
  Application manifest generation completed successfully
  Begin Xap packaging
BUILD SUCCESS.

Deploying to device ...
Connecting to device :: 30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E : Device
Installing app on Device
Launching app on Device
EXIT


F:\Workplace\TestSenchaApp\cordova>
```

### Update 3

Here are commands I ran to generate app and deploy on my device:

1. sencha -sdk /path/to/touch-sdk generate app TestSenchaApp TestSenchaApp
2. cd TestSenchaApp
3. sencha cordova init com.test.myApp
4. edit 'cordova.local.properties'
   4a. change the line cordova.platforms=ios to cordova.platforms=wp8
   4b. save the file and exit your editor
5. sencha ant cordova-sencha-prepare
6. cd cordova
7. cordova serve wp8  -> I tested on IE, Chrome and Firefox, it runs on all of them without an error.
8. cordova run --device

Ran step 8, still got the same issue.

Comment: I already had some problem with the native build of cmd, so now I aways use the build "package". Because the package you can run on your browser or on target browser (mobile). Running on your browser is great because you can check for errors. Your error (3 points blinks) is some javascript error (because the 3 points are only a loading that are replaced after the javascript is loaded). Did you already checked the requires?

Comment: @Scoup Oh great! finally got a feedback. Thanks bro! Now I tried to build the package by using: sencha app build package. and Than I copied all files under build/package/MySenCha into the cordova/www folder. And run: cordova run wp8. What difference is that it looks better(previously there were 3 square dots, not they are around dots), but still it then stops at there....please help. thank you

Comment: You can run your package on desktop browser and check for errors. 3 square or around dots is only the css. You can check it in index.html.  Theres a little diferences about package and build, I don't know all (fair documentation), but for experience I aways use package. I belive the error is some dependency. You need to put require when you use the components.

Comment: Can you show all the app.js code? When you run on developer mode the microloader load all requires "on-the-fly", but when you build it the cmd only load what you really need (that is why you need to put the "requires").

Comment: @Scoup Hi thanks to your help. Sure, I have updated my answer, please find the app.js and app.json in the section Update 1. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I spotted the culprit of this problem.

It was because I have a messy cordova at .cordova/lib.
So what I did was deleted the entire .cordova under C:\Users\\

And reinstalled cordova.

Then the problem solved :)

For more detailed information please see here :
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282942-App-runs-but-stuck-at-the-loading-screen(3-dots-screen)

At #15

Hope it helps, cheers

Answer (score 0):

@Franva, now I can see the problem. Is really the "require". I will explain:

Sencha Touch is a framework with a lot of [components](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/components). When you use the "x-type" you are using a inheritence of a specific component.

Example:

"Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel"": you are using [Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel), and the components are modular in sencha, you can see the source [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/source/Panel2.html#Ext-Panel)

When you are developing, the micro-loader of sencha touch will load this file "on the fly" for you. But when you use cmd, the generated package will only contain the parts of sencha touch that you define. That is to not make a package with big size with components that you wont use.

So, for your package works you have to define the requires in your components/app.
If going to use MVC (model-view-controller) or another multiple files system to create your app so you can put the requires specifics for each file, the cmd will add the component once.

The list of components that you are using:

- Ext.tab.Panel
- Ext.dataview.NestedList
- Ext.Panel
- Ext.form.Panel
- Ext.field.Text
- Ext.field.TextArea
- Ext.field.Email
- Ext.Button

If you open your console on development (ff or chrome) sencha touch will show you a warning about this missing requires.

I didnt search about another errors, but with this change require everything probably will show:

```
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'Ext.tab.Panel',
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.field.Text',
    'Ext.field.TextArea',
    'Ext.field.Email',
    'Ext.Button',
],
```

You should read the docs about compoenents, will help you.

Comment: thx a lot for your great help!!!! Now I added those components in app.json, but when running : sencha cordova init com.text.myApp   I got errors like :  Failed to resolve package Ext.MessageBox

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood. This requires you need to update in your JS file, in this case on your app.js

Comment: hi Scoup, thank you for your timely reply. I removed those in json and added them in js, but still doesn't work.(it works on browser without an error!) I got more information at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282942-App-runs-but-stuck-at-the-loading-screen(3-dots-screen)&p=1035075#post1035075   could you please have a look?

Comment: Btw, I saw a sign, that the 3 dots don't even blink, that means the relative js isn't found. I guess

Comment: I have updated my post with the log. I hope it can give you more insight about what could be wrong in my app. thx mate

Comment: Did you run the build/package on your browser and no errors? If you have some server (Apache, ngix, node, etc) you can use it to access the same package with your mobile browser and see if works or not. Then you can see if the problem is with sencha package or cordova.

Comment: Hi Scoup, yes, I did: sencha app build package.  and ran on device, still the same problem...

Comment: If you use adb with eclipse you can see the console log on Android devices and errors and warning (using logcat). That can be a good start. The log on cordova build dont help too much, because the problem is on javascript. So you need to try to find this error on chrome console of your build/package, the error will probably show there like a undefined var or another error.

Comment: Hi Scoup, thank you for your reply. I did check the errors in the Chrome console, the result was there was no error. But when I open it in Firefox and got many errors in its console. But all of them were css style errors like -moz-xxx is deprecated. Besides that, nothing else. It's so weird that seems I am the only one who cannot run Sencha on a device on this world.... >_<;

Comment: Hi Scoup, I have sloved this problem. Please see update. Cheers :)